# Turbotable : p-tableHeaderCheckbox selects disabled lines

Tags: primeng-turbotable

I am facing a problem on PrimeNG TurboTable.

I started from the following example: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/selection and more particularly from the Checkbox Selection example.

The only difference is that on some p-tableCheckbox I added a **[disabled]="true"**

[image]

This works very well if I select a disabled line it does not activate and can not be selected, but when I click on p-tableHeaderCheckbox all the lines are selected even the lines in disabled.

[image]

In addition, the selection also counts the lines in status disabled or it should only take lines with no status disabled
I made an example on stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gnbsml?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

How to prevent tableHeaderCheckbox from also selecting disable lines?

Thank you in advance for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's failing when we have only disabled rows after filter. I have fixed it by checking active rows.

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const orig_updateCheckedState = this._headerCheckBox.updateCheckedState;
    const me = this;
    this._headerCheckBox.updateCheckedState = function() {
        const cars: any[] = me._table.filteredValue || me._table.value;
        const selection: any[] = me._table.selection;
        let actRows: boolean = false;
        for (const car of cars) {
            if (!me.isRowDisabled(car)) {
                actRows = true;
                const selected = selection && selection.indexOf(car) >= 0;
                if (!selected) return false;
            }
        }
        if (actRows) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can prevent selection in (selectionChange) callback on table. Split [(selection)] on two part:

```
[selection]="selectedRowData" (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)"
```

Add onSelectionChange method to component:

```
  onSelectionChange(selection: any[]) {
    for (let i = selection.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      let data = selection[i];
      if (this.isRowDisabled(data)) {
        selection.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
    this.selectedRowData = selection;
 }
```

Also add isRowDisabled method:

```
  isRowDisabled(data: any): boolean {
    return data.color === 'orange'
  }
```

and change template for tableCheckbox to use isRowDisabled (it's only for check in one place)

```
<p-tableCheckbox [value]="rowData" [disabled]="isRowDisabled(rowData)"></p-tableCheckbox>
```

See example on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hnzxs2 (I am also add logic to exclude disabled rows from process of calculating state of headerCheckBox)

Answer (score 0):

just use onRowSelect

html

```
<p-table (onRowSelect)="isRowSelectable($event)" ....
```

ts

```
isRowSelectable(event) {
     return event.data.xxx === true;
}
```